# A Good Tool/Library For Turning C Headers into XML

Tags: c++, c, xml

I am looking for a good tool or library that takes a C/Cpp/header file and generates xml for the functions in that file.

So Perhaps

```
float foo(int bar, char* str);
```

would turn into

```
<function name="foo" returntype="float">
    <params>
        <param dataType="int">bar</param>
        <param dataType="char*">str</param>
    </params>
</function>
```

This is likely a stupid question, I looked through visual studio, found some things on C Sharp and VB. Sadly, Googling C++/C and XML in the same line turns up almost entirely posts on C++ Generating XML from other files.

I all else fails I can write my own, just wondering if there was a good tool out there that I had not heard of.

Comment: "I all else fails I can write my own" Parsing C++ is not that easy. C is fairly easy, but C++? No.

Comment: yeah, tell us why, we're a curious bunch you know..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at Doxygen.

Among other things, it can [generate XML](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/output.html). IIRC you can [configure](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html#cfg_extract_all) Doxygen to produce XML even for functions without specially formatted comments, if that's what you want.

Comment: Doxygen's XML output is somewhere between terrible and godawful. I tried using it for something, but it very rarely works. If you want to convert it into something that doesn't look like Doxygen's HTML docs, you're in trouble. Or you need to do some extra parsing on your own.

Comment: I also recommend using Doxygen.  It's true that the XML output doesn't look the best, but it *is* usable.  You'll most likely end up spending some time playing with Doxygen options and writing XML parsing scripts, but all of that is typically much easier than the C++ --> XML conversion step.

Comment: I took a look into the XML Doxygen generates. It will serve decently, I think. I would kinda prefer to not have the user need to use doxygen first, then send the XML into our program, so I will likely write my own parser(I have very specific cases). That being said, if anyone else is looking for a general tool, this one looks the best, or at least best from a simple/easy to effective ratio. So thank you @Branko

Answer (score 1):

What you should be googling instead is "parsing C++". With a ready-made parser for C++, you can walk through a representation of the abstract syntax tree and generate whatever you want from it.

Good open source C++ parsing libraries are, I believe, somewhat thinner on the ground than their counterparts for languages like C#, but you here's a project you might find useful - [GCC-XML](http://www.gccxml.org/HTML/Index.html), which uses the GCC front end and writes an XML emitting back end. Here's another interesting page on [C++ parsing resources](http://www.nobugs.org/developer/parsingcpp/).

At worst, you could take the output of GCC-XML and simply transform THAT XML into what you need.

Standard disclaimer - I've never used GCC-XML, your mileage may vary, etc...